# How to fix config file error on shiny-server start

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, config, shiny-server

In my Ubuntu terminal (version 18.04), when I type the command `shiny-server` or `sudo shiny-server` I am met with the error message

> Error loading config: File "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf" does not exist

The file `shiny-server.conf` does exist at `C:/Users/Me/shiny-server/config/upstart`, albeit not with the same contents as found on the site. I swapped the contents with those found on the `shiny` website to no avail.

I took the config file `shiny-server.conf` from the shiny website and pasted the contents into a file located at `C:/Users/Me/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem either.

Not quite sure how I should go about rectifying this problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why does your Ubuntu Linux have MS Windows drive letters?

Comment: I'm not sure, I didn't know that's not something that happens. My computer runs on Windows 10 and I downloaded Ubuntu yesterday to download shiny server. Hopefully that answers your question. Whenever I give the full path of "C:/….." that's on my Windows, not Ubuntu... does that suggest I should be looking for "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf" somewhere in Ubuntu? @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: I don't know what you're doing. If you're running Ubuntu inside of a virtual machine, then you need to look inside that machine. For a start, make a list of the steps you take after logging into Windows in order to get to that error. That would at least make it clear what's going on.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt , Here's the steps I take : 1)Start up Windows, 2)Open my Ubuntu app, 3) cd shiny-server, 4) sudo shiny-server … I then receive the following four messages : 
[INFO] Shiny Server V 1.5.12.0 (Node.js v10.15.3)
[INFO] Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[ERROR] Error loading config: File "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf" does not exist
[INFO] Shutting down worker process

Comment: Okay final update: I was able to locate /etc/shiny-server which was an existing directory and pasted the default config from RStudio site into the folder. After restarting Ubuntu, the file appeared and was able to be run. I got a new error but it's over the config file. Thanks @UlrichEckhardt for helping me rubber duck lol take care